# How unused Index cause performance degradation

Tags: sql-server

I was going through various articles on Missing indices and Unused Indices. Was wondering how having multiple indices which are un-used causes performance issues.

1. How does it effect the performance? ( Did not find any explanation or proof of concept)
2. Also confused as some articles say dropping them can cause performance issues too. Is it for all cases or any specific?

Comment: There is an additional cost for maintaining indices when inserting, updating or deleting information from tables. Even though an index is not used for queries, it still has to be maintained during modification of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> having multiple indices which are un-used causes performance issues

Every index comes at a cost. If you have `OLTP` system full of `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, all these operation make double work if there is an index on your table.

Even when you use DWH and your data are stable enough, every unused index means waste of space. And this means your backups will take more time, and when backup is taken all the queries run slower because backup is IO intensive

Comment: So DML operations are mainly affected? What if its read intensive, will it have an impact. ?

Comment: @RamakantDadhichi, the optimizer considers available indexes during query plan generation. This can increase compilation time for non-trivial queries when many indexes exist and increase the likelihood of a suboptimal plan.

Comment: Marking as answer as this thread explains well. Not sure why the question was downvoted. Really afraid to ask any..